# Flutter web build: Contact Picker API considered Insecure

Tags: flutter, security, flutter-cupertino

I'm using `flutter build web` to generate a web application which uses the `fluttercontactpicker` package, which claims to have support for the Contact Picker API for web.

The main problem is I'm running the app on Safari and Safari mobile (iOS 17.0) and I receive the following error: "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.", but `window.isSecureContext === true`, and `FlutterContactPicker.available` returns true.

The code:

```
Future presentContactDialog() async {
    print(FlutterContactPicker.available);
    try {
      final PhoneContact contact =
          await FlutterContactPicker.pickPhoneContact();
      if (contact.fullName != null) {
        // HANDLING
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      showCupertinoDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: const Text("Impossibile operare sui contatti"),
                actions: [
                  CupertinoButton(
                      child: const Text("OK"),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
                ],
              ));
    }
  }
```

The page is deployed on an HTTPS (certbot) website.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. `flutter build web`
2. upload to my website through ftp the build/web directory
3. install the PWA
4. start Safari web inspector
5. tap the widget which calls the function